# How do I make this JavaScript compatible with "use strict"?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
window.onload = function() {
  init();
  var date = new Date();
  var dd = date.getDate();
  var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

  //Add a zero if one Digit (eg: 05,09)
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = "0" + dd;
  }

  //Add a zero if one Digit (eg: 05,09)
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = "0" + mm;
  }

  minYear = yyyy - 80; //Calculate Minimun Age (<80)
  maxYear = yyyy - 15; //Calculate Maximum Age (>18)

  var min = minYear + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
  var max = maxYear + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;

  document.getElementById("start").setAttribute("min", min);
  document.getElementById("start").setAttribute("max", max);

};
```

I know the issue is that "minYear" and "maxYear" are undeclared variables, but I'm not sure how I'm meant to declare them without breaking the code entirely?

Comment: There is a now deleted question asking about the same code: [Why doesn't "use strict" work with my JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69432640)

Comment: Why would you expect your script to break if you simply declared them with `var`?

Comment: @Bergi When I run it through a validator it says that it's undeclared. I have no reason to believe anything else is causing it to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`minYear` and `maxYear` are variables like the others (date, dd, mm, etc...).

You should declare them using the "var " prefix, the first time you are using them.

```
var minYear = yyyy - 80;
var maxYear = yyyy - 15;
```